# Netsuite Add Custom Fied to Transaction Column Field

Tags: netsuite

On "Reconcile Credit Card Statement" screen of Netsuite UI, at "Payment and Credit" section (the list), I want to add one more column into it. And this column is referred to the custom field of the Payment.

Can we do that?

Any help is appreciate!
Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a standard scripted screen, and as such cannot be customised.
You'll notice the lack of both "Customise" on the sublist view, and also at the top right of the screen.
You could always contact NetSuite Support and get them to raise it as an enhancement request to be able to customise the sublist view itself...?

Thanks

Pete.

Comment: Thanks Pete! I appreciate that, I still looking for the clue to explain to the customer.